# Postfix + SASL SQLite gives auxprop error on CentOS 7

Tags: postfix, centos7, sasl, sqlite

I am receiving an `unknown password verifier(s) auxprop` error when trying to use SQLite for SASL authentication in Postfix on CentOS 7.  It seems that the SQLite SQL engine is not found.

Contents of `/etc/sasl2/smtp.conf`:

```
log_level: 127
pwcheck_method: auxprop
auxprop_plugin: sql
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 NTLM
sql_engine: sqlite
sql_database: /etc/postfix/sasl_db
sql_select: SELECT password FROM users WHERE user = '%u'
```

Connection documented in `/var/log/maillog`:

```
Jul 25 08:55:43 smtp2 postfix/smtpd[5049]: connect a.b.c.d.myisp.net[a.b.c.d]
Jul 25 08:55:45 smtp2 postfix/smtpd[5049]: warning: SASL authentication problem: unknown password verifier(s) auxprop
Jul 25 08:55:45 smtp2 postfix/smtpd[5049]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Jul 25 08:55:45 smtp2 postfix/smtpd[5049]: warning: a.b.c.d.myisp.net[a.b.c.d]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: no mechanism available
Jul 25 08:55:46 smtp2 postfix/smtpd[5049]: warning: SASL authentication problem: unknown password verifier(s) auxprop
Jul 25 08:55:46 smtp2 postfix/smtpd[5049]: warning: a.b.c.d.myisp.net[a.b.c.d]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: no mechanism available
Jul 25 08:55:51 smtp2 postfix/smtpd[5049]: disconnect from a.b.c.d.myisp.net[a.b.c.d]
```

There's a hint in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Jul 25 08:55:38 smtp2 systemd: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Jul 25 08:55:38 smtp2 systemd: Started Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
Jul 25 08:55:43 smtp2 postfix/smtpd[5049]: SQL engine 'sqlite' not supported
Jul 25 08:55:43 smtp2 postfix/smtpd[5049]: auxpropfunc error no mechanism available
```

I tried replacing `sqlite` with `sqlite3` (and restarting Postfix), same result.

My best guess so far is that I'm missing a rpm, but can't identify what it might be.

```
smtp2:/# rpm --query -a | grep -ie sqlite -ie sasl -ie postfix
cyrus-sasl-sql-2.1.26-23.el7.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-md5-2.1.26-23.el7.x86_64
sqlite-3.7.17-8.el7_7.1.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.26-23.el7.x86_64
postfix-2.10.1-9.el7.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-2.1.26-23.el7.x86_64
libsqlite3x-20071018-20.el7.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-plain-2.1.26-23.el7.x86_64
smtp2:/# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
```

Am I missing a needed rpm, or more generally, how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging, it looks like SQLite support is not enabled in the CentOS version of SASL, and cannot be added through a module/plugin.

I think direct SQLite support would involve rebuilding SASL.  A better solution might be to use `saslauthd` and access SQLite via PAM, i.e. something like this in `/etc/pam.d/smtp`:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth        required    pam_sqlite3.so 
account     required    pam_sqlite3.so
```

Hopefully this also helps someone else.